# Eslint AirBNB with 4 spaces for indent

Tags: eslint

I am configuring eslint and am using the AirBNB style guide.

I want to over-ride the indent (supposed to be 2 spaces) to be 4 spaces. But no matter what I do within my .eslintrc I cannot get this error supressed so that I can use indentation of 4 spaces.

I have the message "Expected indentation of 2 spaces chatacters but found 4. (react/jsx-indent)" everywhere within my code base.

I am using eslint 4.9.0. How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: related issue on github https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1141

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this is for indenting props, not for general code.

Comment: One more way is to remove entirely this plugin (Until the core team will better User experience - it does not make sense to throw `Failed to compile` because of one extra white space or indentation ): `npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint`

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Ok so this is relatively easy to do and is achievable by adding the following to your eslint config:

```
// Indent with 4 spaces
"indent": ["error", 4],

// Indent JSX with 4 spaces
"react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4],

// Indent props with 4 spaces
"react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 4],
```

Comment: where should i add it? where is eslint config file?

Comment: This caused statements, like switches, to be flattened. Eg, `case xyz:` will be required to be at the same level of `switch (cond) {`.

Comment: @OhadR eddited the answer to also reflect your question

Comment: @OhadR Add it to the `rules` property of your eslint config, which should be a `.eslintrc` file in your project's root directory (same folder as the `package.json` file), though the extension of the file varies. It can also be inside your `package.json`.

Answer (score 30):

The code from Notorious's answer should be added to **rules** field in the ESlint config.

```js
module.exports = {
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        // enable additional rules
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"],
        "semi": ["error", "always"],

        // override default options for rules from base configurations
        "comma-dangle": ["error", "always"],
        "no-cond-assign": ["error", "always"],

        // disable rules from base configurations
        "no-console": "off",
    }
}
```

[ [Source](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) - see ***Using "eslint:recommended"***]

Comment: This seems like much more than the OP asked.

Comment: This was an answer to question asked by @OhadR about where should these rules be put into. This is example of ESlint config.

Answer (score 10):

Since the accepted answer is incomplete and that answer's edit queue is full, I'm adding this complement:

**To Simply Disable** the 2-space ident rule, add the following line to the `rules` property of your esling config file:

```js
"indent": "off",
```

**To Override the Rule** (probably what you want) to check for 4-space idents rather than 2 spaces, add the following line instead:

```js
"indent": ["error", 4],
```

It should look like this:

```js
// eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb",
  ],
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 4],
  },
};
```

### ESLint config location

Your eslint config might be in any of the following files:

1. `.eslintrc.js`
2. `.eslintrc.cjs`
3. `.eslintrc.yaml`
4. `.eslintrc.yml`
5. `.eslintrc.json`
6. `.eslintrc`
7. or it might be inside your `package.json`, in an `"eslintConfig"` property.

More about eslint config: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring (under header "Configuration File Formats")

Comment: those locations was what I was looking for, thanks!